# Sum of proper divisors

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, programming-challenge

> Given a natural number \$n\$ (\$1 \le n \le 500000\$), please output the
>   summation of all its proper divisors.
>
> **Definition**: A proper divisor of a natural number is the divisor that is strictly less than the number.
>
> e.g. number 20 has 5 proper divisors: 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, and the divisor
>   summation is: 1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 10 = 22.
>
> **Input**
>
> An integer stating the number of test cases (equal to about 200000),
>   and that many lines follow, each containing one integer between 1 and
>   500000 inclusive.
>
> **Output**
>
> One integer each line: the divisor summation of the integer given
>   respectively.

**My solution:**

It solved the problem in 1.63 seconds, which seems suboptimal considering its 3-second limit.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testcases = reader.nextInt();
        reader.nextLine();
        ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i<testcases; i++){
            values.add(reader.nextInt());
            reader.nextLine();
        }
        reader.close();
        for(int i = 0; i<testcases; i++){
            int sum = 1;
            int testcase = values.get(i);
            double lim = Math.sqrt(testcase);
            for(int k = 2; k<=lim; k++){
                if(testcase%k==0){
                    sum+=k;
                    int z = testcase/k;
                    if(k != z)
                        sum+=z;
                }
            }
            if(testcase==1)
                sum=0;
            if(i<testcases-1)
                System.out.println(sum);
            else
                System.out.print(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT: Updated code**, which ran in a more respectable 0.22 seconds.

Taking out `reader.nextLine();` improved the runtime by around 0.2 seconds.

Adding a special treatment to perfect squares seemed to have no noticable impact on speed (might depend on test cases?).

It turned out using `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` had an immense impact on IO speed, reducing runtime to 0.22 seconds.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
        int testcases = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        int[] values = new int[testcases];
        for(int i = 0; i<testcases; i++){
            values[i]=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            }
        for(int i = 0; i<testcases; i++){
            int sum = 1;
            int testcase = values[i];
            double lim = Math.sqrt(testcase);
            for(int k = 2; k<lim; k++){
                if(testcase % k == 0){
                    sum += k + testcase / k;
                }
            }
            int intLim = (int) lim;
            if (intLim * intLim == testcase) {
                sum += lim;
            }
            if(testcase == 1)
                sum=0;
            out.write(sum + "\n");
        }
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested this locally, and most of the time is due to IO: running in Eclipse with 200.000 random numbers (producing 6.2MB output) it takes 4.7 seconds, on the commandline 2.9 seconds, and on the commandline redirecting stdout to  a file it takes 1 second. Without printing any output the algorithm takes 120ms.

Comment: @Kenney Interesting. How could I decrease IO time?

Comment: I tried buffering all output and do a `System.out.write` but that doesn't speed things up. The only way that I know is to output to a file instead of stdout, as this bypasses the OS rendering terminals and such. Btw, your algorithm will miss some output: for example `sqrt(20)` is about 4.47 so you will miss divisors 5 and 10.

Comment: This may not have a big impact, but `Scanner` is a beast, performance-wise. Use a `BufferedReader` and `Integer.parseInt()`. --- Also, you are wasting time building an `ArrayList<Integer>`, boxing all the values and building up the list. Just perform your logic as you read the values. --- You should move the inside of the `for` loop to a method that returns the sum, and print in the caller. This will allow adding unit tests to your code, and isolates the logic from the I/O, for a better structured program.

Comment: @Andreas using `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` indeed had quite a big impact on IO speed. The code ran in 0.22 seconds. I also used an integer array instead of an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Dang. I knew from other Stack Exchange posts that `Scanner` was a beast, but reducing run time from 1.63 seconds to 0.22 seconds is a much bigger impact than I had anticipated. *Conclusion:* Avoid use of `Scanner` except for small classroom exercises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the innermost `for` loop,
you have a condition to check in every cycle if `k` is the square root.
But most of the time it's *not* equal to the square root.
It would be more optimal to rework that,
and add a special treatment for square numbers once, after the loop:

```
for (int k = 2; k < lim; k++) {
    if (testcase % k == 0) {
        sum += k + testcase / k;
    }
}
int intLim = (int) lim;
if (intLim * intLim == testcase) {
    sum += lim;
}
```

---

You don't need the `reader.nextLine()` calls in this code,
you can safely remove them.
You can also remove the `reader.close()`,
no need to close `System.in`.

```
int testcases = reader.nextInt();
//reader.nextLine();
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < testcases; i++) {
    values.add(reader.nextInt());
    //reader.nextLine();
}
//reader.close();
```

---

Is it really important to not print a newline at the end?
If it's not important, then you can rewrite the loop as a for-each loop:

```
for (int testcase : values) {
    // ...
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

---

Minor things:

- It's better to declare variables with interface types when possible, so instead of `ArrayList<Integer> values = ...`, use `List<Integer> values = ...`
- As of Java 7, use the diamond operator `<>` when creating parameterized types, for example `List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>()`
- Always use braces even with single-statement if/else/for
- Put spaces around operators and parentheses, for example instead of `if(testcase%k==0){` write as `if (testcase % k == 0) {`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         for(int i = 0; i<testcases; i++){
>             int sum = 1;
>             int testcase = values.get(i);
> ```

You never use `i` outside these three lines, so you could just as well write

```
        for (int testcase : values) {
            int sum = 1;
```

I would consider either renaming `testcase` to `value`, or renaming `testcases` to `testcaseCount` and `values` to `testcases`.  I would prefer the latter, mostly because I prefer plural variable names to refer to collections.

Before that, you might want to add

```
        int lastValue = values.remove(values.size() - 1);
```

Then you can replace

> ```
>             if(i<testcases-1)
>                 System.out.println(sum);
>             else
>                 System.out.print(sum);
> ```

with just

```
            System.out.println(sum);
```

and handle the last value separately.